# `df.query()` in polars?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-polars

What is the equivalent of **[pandas.DataFrame.query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas-dataframe-query)** in polars?

```
import pandas as pd
data= {
    'A':["Polars","Python","Pandas"],
    'B' :[23000,24000,26000],
    'C':['30days', '40days',np.nan],
      }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    A        B       C
0   Polars  23000   30days
1   Python  24000   40days
2   Pandas  26000   NaN
```

Now, defining a variable `item`

```
item=24000
df.query("B>= @item")

    A        B       C
1   Python  24000   40days
2   Pandas  26000   NaN
```

Now, using polars:

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(data)

item=24000
df.query("B>= @item")
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'query'
```

My wild guess is `df.filter()` but syntax does not look same and `filter` looks equivalent to `df.loc[]` as well ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

indeed, filter is all you need

```
df.filter(pl.col("B") >= item)
```

clean, simple, predictable, without hacks